# Redis multi insert issue

Tags: bash, redis, command-line-interface

I try to multi-insert but it gives me error -
http://pastie.org/7337421

```
$ cat mass_insert.txt 
*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n
$ cat mass_insert.txt | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try the following: 

`echo -e "$(cat mass_insert.txt)" | redis-cli --pipe`