# Is Redis mass insertion (using client's --pipe) so restricted?

Tags: redis, bulkinsert

I prepared a file according to redis' mass insertion protocol, and everything is working fine. Up to a point...

If the file contains up to 775 commands, all is good:

```
% redis-cli --pipe < in.redis
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 775
```

But starting at 776 commands, this is what I get:

```
% redis-cli --pipe < in.redis
Error writing to the server: No error
```

It seems unreasonable that there is such a tiny limit.
Plus, as you can see, the error message is fishy.

Anyone seen such a behavior? Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running the win64 version of redis (version 2.8.9)

Comment: What is the content of the line 776? Did you try to replace it with some other content?

Comment: Note that each command is more than one line, so there are around 5500 lines. But anyway: no matter what is the 776th command, this weird error appears (while all cases of <=775 commands are always fine).

Answer (score 0):

In certain shells, there seems to be potential for interpreter errors to the \r and \n bytes that are needed for the Redis protocol.  The error message you reported doesn't match exactly, but the behavior sounds somewhat similar to what is being described in this SO question:

[Redis multi insert issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848126/redis-multi-insert-issue)

Long shot, but you might try this:

```
echo "$(cat in.redis)" | redis-cli --pipe
```

Comment: Yes, seen those discussions, but I'm using windows, and "hexdump -C < in.redis" shows the 0d 0a clearly.